# Who can see a comment I write in Google+? Does it depend on who can see the original post?

Tags: google-plus

In Google+, I'm not sure who can see a comment I make on a post. Is it open to the world, or just to people that can see the original post? (I realize that the set of people who can see a post can expand over time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the people that can see the original post can see the comment.

See [Who sees the content you post in the stream](http://www.google.com/support/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1053543&topic=1257360):

> When you +1 or comment on a post, whoever can view the original post will be able to see your +1 and comment as well.